# What are the differences between ORM injection and SQL injection?

Tags: security, orm, sql-injection, code-injection

I have read about ORM injection and SQL injection. In many sites it has been said that ORM injection is almost as same as SQL injection in a testers point of view. So what basically i want to know is the major differences between ORM and SQL injections.

It will be helpful if a brief idea on ORM is also explained.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently both SQL injection and ORM injection seems to be same. But there is difference between them. ORM injection attack is carried out using SQL injection attack.
ORM generated objects can use SQL to perform basic operations like create, update, delete on a database. So indirectly, SQL injection attacks can be performed on such objects where input parameters are not sanitized properly! :)